# Novel about cultivator in a world of magic

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a book on kindle then forgot the title when I returned it.  The story was basically a body cultivator it put into a young child in a world of magic.  Or it might have been the reverse.  In his original world he was like a high end government operative with all these magic like skills.  There were these elite level operatives and they all knew each other.

Something happens and he is tossed into a body on another world of a young kid? or reborn?  He hides his skills and goes around in the underworld of the new world building a organization, gets a restaurant, helps a kid in a alley being beat up and has him work of him.  That's what I can remember.  I can't find it on Amazon.  Came out earlier 2018.

Comment: What is a "body cultivator"?

Comment: Asian magic type. they cultivate the chi? in the body to increase strength speed and get skills from it. iron fist, etc.. see a lot in Asian fantasy, this is a either Asian body cultivator going to a western type magic world, or the reverse. can't remember which.